# Minimal Intersection layout algorithm

Tags: javascript, graph, d3.js

I would like to know if is there any example of a Minimal Intersection layout algorithm (not force-based) for graphs, so I could adapt it to d3.js.

Comment: is this what you're looking to implement? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vertex_cover_problem

Answer (score 9):

Computing the layout of a graph that minimizes edge crossings is NP-hard, so there's no single algorithm; there are different algorithms with different trade-offs. The force-based layout ([Fruchterman–Reingold](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Force-based_algorithms_%28graph_drawing%29)) is one approach, layered ([Sugiyama](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Layered_graph_drawing)) is another. There are also layouts for specific types of graphs, such as trees ([Reingold–Tilford](http://emr.cs.iit.edu/~reingold/tidier-drawings.pdf)) and small worlds ([van Ham–van Wijk](http://www.research.ibm.com/visual/papers/smallworld.pdf)). Constrained layout such as Dig-CoLa ([Dwyer–Koren](http://www2.research.att.com/~north/papers_videos/pdf/DBLP-conf-infovis-DwyerK05.pdf)) is yet another class of algorithm.

If you want an algorithm that specifically seeks to minimize the number of edge crossings, you could use [simulated annealing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simulated_annealing). While this will eventually find the right answer, it can be quite slow.